# How to raycast against a physx cloth mesh?

Tags: c++, physx

I'm using the PhysX 3.3 SDK in a application and mostly everything is working fine. However, I'm trying to develop a feature that would allow users to click on various actors in the scene and modify their properties.

My approach so far has been to use the PhysX raycast to query the scene and use RaycastHit to return a pointer to the actor. This works fine for rigid bodies, but for cloth actors, the hit is invariably null.

This suggests that PhysX can't raycast against cloth objects, but other than my tests, I haven't seen anything in the docs (or on the interwebs) that say this definitively.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not to say this question is off-topic here, but you might hit a wider pool of experience over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.